# JavaScript Prevent Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to get my form to not submit when I press the cancel button on my JavaScript dialog.

I have this code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this).attr("href"); // "get" the intended link in a var
        var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to log this fault?");
        if (result) {
            document.location.href = link;  // if result, "set" the document location      
        }
    });
});
```

The form submits regardless if I press the Ok or Cancel buttons or not even though I have the prevent default code.

My HTML code is:

```
<button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span></button>
```

Comment: That form never submits ?

Comment: Post your HTML please.

Comment: So, you don't want to submit the form at all? and go to "link" if user selects "ok"? and do nothing for "cancel"?

Comment: No I dont want to submit the form if the user clicks cancel. If the user clicks ok I would like it to progress though as normal and go ahead with submission

Comment: And why is this? document.location.href = link; if you are submitting the form? and can you add your form html as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="/the/post/url">

<!-- other elements -->
....
....
....

<button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span>
</button>

</form>

$(function() {
    //this would do the same as button click as both submit the form
    $(document).on("submit", "#myform", function (e) {
        var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to log this fault?");
        //if cancel is cliked
        if (!result) {
             return false;      
        }
        //if ok is cliked, form will be submitted
    });
});
```

Comment: my HTML from code is @using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "Incident", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "frm", id = "frm"}))

Answer (score 0):

the following like won't work since `this` reffers to the submit button which does not have an `href` attribute.

```
var link = $(this).attr("href"); // is invalid.
```

try

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to log this fault?");
        if (result) {
        $('#formId').submit(); // where formId is the id of your form
          document.location.href = "url to which you want to redirect";      
        }
        else
        return false;
       });
});
```

*side note: from wherever you got this piece of code, they must be using a hyperlink `<a>` styled like a button, with a valid href attribute :)*

Comment: The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Incident/undefined

Comment: I get the above error with the code provided by @TilwinJoy