# HTML/JavaScript why does my form keep redirecting me and how do I stop it?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying out JS for the first time, and I'm trying to carry out a few basic tasks just to check everything works, and when I click submit to simply check some variables show them with 'alert', I am returned a 404 page not found. I haven't been able to find anything helpful. I have tried action="#" in the form tag and also the prevent.Default method I found but so far to no avail. Below is my HTML and JavaScript files. Thanks in advance!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css">
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
<title>Classical Ciphers Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper_ciphers">
<div id="container_ciphers">
<div id="heading"><h1><br>Classical <br>Ciphers</h1></div>
    <div id="caesar_cipher">
        <div id="inner_caesar"><h1>Caesar Cipher</h1>
        <form onSubmit="caesarEncipher()">
            <input type="text" id="caesar_text" required>
            <input type="text" id="caesar_key" required>
            <input id="caesar_submit" type="submit" value="Submit" >
        </form>

    </div>
    <div id="hill_cipher">
        <div id="inner_hill"><h1>Hill Cipher</h1></div>
    </div>
    <div id="vigenere_cipher">
        <div id="inner_vigenere"><h1>Vigenere Cipher</h1></div>
    </div>
</div></div>
```

here is the JavaScript file.

```
function validateKey(){
alert("Hello");
if(isNAN(document.getElementById("caesar_key").value)){
    alert("Please input a valid number")
}   
}

function caesarEncipher(){
validateKey();
alert(document.getElementById("caesar_key").value))

}
```

Comment: a form submits data to the server and loads a new page (the action attribute, which defaults to the current url) - there are plenty of questions on SO about **prevent**ing a forms **Default** submit action ... (return false in the `onsubmit` attribute is one way)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Prevent Form Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22437249/javascript-prevent-form-submit)

Comment: I saw some posts like that and it wasn't immediately clear how to resolve my own problem. Also many were talking about jQuery whereas I am not supposed to include any external library's - this is for uni coursework!

Comment: `return false` to prevent a form from submitting is jQuery only. You need to use `event.preventDefault` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it by taking away the form tags and just dealt with the individual elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css">
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
<title>Classical Ciphers Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper_ciphers">
<div id="container_ciphers">
<div id="heading"><h1><br>Classical <br>Ciphers</h1></div>
    <div id="caesar_cipher">
        <div id="inner_caesar"><h1>Caesar Cipher</h1>
            <input type="text" id="caesar_text" >
            <input type="text" id="caesar_key" >
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="caesarEncipher()" >


    </div>
    <div id="hill_cipher">
        <div id="inner_hill"><h1>Hill Cipher</h1></div>
    </div>
    <div id="vigenere_cipher">
        <div id="inner_vigenere"><h1>Vigenere Cipher</h1></div>
    </div>
</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the JS

```
function caesarEncipher(){
if (document.getElementById("caesar_text").value === "") {
            alert("Please enter some text to encipher.");
            return false;
        } else if (document.getElementById("caesar_key").value === "") {
            alert("Please enter a valid key.");
            return false;
        }
if(isNaN(document.getElementById("caesar_key").value))  {
    alert("Please input a valid number");
    return false;
}
alert(document.getElementById("caesar_key").value); 
}
```

and it all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

To not submit by default, try below

```
<form onSubmit="caesarEncipher(); return false;">
```

and I would use error checking like this.

```
if(document.getElementById("caesar_key").value == ""){
```

```js
function validateKey(){
 alert("Hello");
  if(document.getElementById("caesar_key").value == ""){
    alert("Please input a valid number")
  }   
}

function caesarEncipher(){
  validateKey();
  alert(document.getElementById("caesar_key").value)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css">
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
<title>Classical Ciphers Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper_ciphers">
<div id="container_ciphers">
<div id="heading"><h1><br>Classical <br>Ciphers</h1></div>
    <div id="caesar_cipher">
        <div id="inner_caesar"><h1>Caesar Cipher</h1>
        <form onSubmit="caesarEncipher(); return false;">
            <input type="text" id="caesar_text" required>
            <input type="text" id="caesar_key" required>
            <input id="caesar_submit" type="submit" value="Submit" >
        </form>

    </div>
    <div id="hill_cipher">
        <div id="inner_hill"><h1>Hill Cipher</h1></div>
    </div>
    <div id="vigenere_cipher">
        <div id="inner_vigenere"><h1>Vigenere Cipher</h1></div>
    </div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I tried many variations of the return false in different places, as that's what all the online info was saying but it never worked. But thankfully I've got it working now anyway. Thanks again!